# GoDaddy DNS Forwading http vs https

Tags: heroku, dns

I've got a website hosted with Heroku, DNS through GoDaddy.

I've setup forwarding so that `example.com` should forward to `www.example.com`.
http forwards properly, https does not:

```
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://example.com -> DNS Error
```

In the Heroku panel, the SSL verification has failed for example.com but succeeded for www.example.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FROM Heroku Support:

Some DNS providers will only offer A records for root domains. Unfortunately, A records will not suffice for pointing your root domains to Heroku because they require a static IP. Since Heroku uses dynamic IP addresses, it’s necessary to use a CNAME-like record (often referred to as ALIAS or ANAME records) so that you can point your root domain to another domain.

GoDaddy only supports A records for root domains and is thus an insufficient DNS provider.

Heroku offers suggestions for alternative DNS providers:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains

EDIT:
Working solution with CloudFlare:

```
SSL Managed Automatically (ACM) on Heroku
SSL Set to "Full" on CloudFlare
CloudFlare DNS Records:
    CNAME, @, mysite.herokudns.com
    CNAME, www, www.mysite.herokudns.com
CloudFlare CNAME statuses set to "DNS Only" (Gray cloud)
Heroku Domains:
    mysite.com
    www.mysite.com
```

Comment: I used cloudflare, it was very easy to configure